# Can't unlock table in MariaDB 10.2

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm using MariaDB 10.2. I have a table that has ~60M rows. Originally was I was trying to run:

```
insert into signals select * from signals_tmp where signal_num = 21;
```

And MariaDB froze. Since then I tried to restart mysqld and my laptop so I don't have the exact state of when it first froze. Now when I tried to do this:

```
select count(*) from signals where signal_num = 20
```

It froze, so I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in MySQL. Then I run the following:

```
MariaDB [phd]> show open tables where In_use = 1;
+----------+---------+--------+-------------+
| Database | Table   | In_use | Name_locked |
+----------+---------+--------+-------------+
| phd      | signals |      1 |           0 |
+----------+---------+--------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [phd]> show processlist;
+----+-------------+-----------------+------+---------+------+--------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+----------+
| Id | User        | Host            | db   | Command | Time | State                    
| Info                                               | Progress |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------+---------+------+--------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+----------+
|  1 | system user |                 | NULL | Daemon  | NULL | InnoDB purge coordinator | NULL                                               |    0.000 |
|  2 | system user |                 | NULL | Daemon  | NULL | InnoDB purge worker      | NULL                                               |    0.000 |
|  3 | system user |                 | NULL | Daemon  | NULL | InnoDB purge worker      | NULL                                               |    0.000 |
|  4 | system user |                 | NULL | Daemon  | NULL | InnoDB purge worker      | NULL                                               |    0.000 |
|  5 | system user |                 | NULL | Daemon  | NULL | InnoDB shutdown handler  | NULL                                               |    0.000 |
|  8 | root        | localhost:50473 | phd  | Killed  |  402 | Sending data             
| select count(*) from signals where signal_num = 20 |    0.000 |
| 10 | root        | localhost:50477 | phd  | Query   |    0 | init                     
| show processlist                                   |    0.000 |
| 11 | root        | localhost:50489 | NULL | Query   |   48 | Filling schema table     | SHOW STATUS                                        |    0.000 
|
+----+-------------+-----------------+------+---------+------+--------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+----------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

When I tried to do flush tables, it hanged there with no CPU usage (i.e., looks like it's not doing anything?).

[EDIT] as per comment, here is the statistics result.

```
MariaDB [(none)]> select distinct COMMENT from information_schema.statistics where TABLE_SCHEMA='phd' and table_schema='signals';
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Any idea what has happened to my database?

Comment: Some simple select statements still work, like select * from signals limit 100, but even show engine innodb status will freeze.

Comment: can you show us:      select  distinct `COMMENT`
    from information_schema.statistics
    where TABLE_SCHEMA='phd' and table_schema='signals';

Comment: Added results to above

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you have an open transaction that needs closing.

```
BEGIN;
...
(program still running, but not COMMIT yet)
```

Otherwise, `SHOW PROCESSLIST` should have shown something.

So...  Look for *clients* that might be in that state; kill them.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried unlock tables, flush tables, restarting my laptop, and nothing worked. So I ended up switching over to SQL Server. Thanks anyway!